# Create New Login based on query string

Tags: php, laravel

My user login for clients is:

```
https: //site.test/public/auth/login
```

And my delivery boys login is the same

```
https: //site.test/public/auth/login
```

But each with different results based on the role of the user.

But I have in the project there are people who use the 2 roles customer and delivery person and have to log out and log in again with the other account.

My question is if you can have an identifier as query string.

Example

```
https: //site.test/public/auth/login?client
https: //site.test/public/auth/login?delivery
```

so that each url is saved with a different token and when sending to the url

In case the urls when the user is logged in based on the role is different

For example

```
https: //site.test/public/delivery/token
https: //site.test/public/client/token
```

But when you access these, user information is crossed.

Comment: `who use the 2 roles customer and delivery person and have to log out and log in again with the other account.`...so just re-design the security part of the code so that once they log in, they have access to all the functionality allowed by all their assigned roles. Making them log in and out again is ridiculous and your proposed solution wouldn't solve that

Comment: @Eduardo I recommend to use PHP-Auth its a great library for your needs.